# Problema de compilación en SQL Developer con un trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, trigger, oracle-sqldeveloper

estoy teniendo un problema cuando trato de compilar en SQL DEVELOPER un trigger(1) a una tabla llamada validaciones(2).

Lo que me piden en el trigger es cuando registres "El número, la fecha y el estado se asigna automáticamente"

Hay tres estados el cual 'E' es significa En espera, 'A' anulado y 'T' terminado.

(1)

```
CREATE TRIGGER Ad_validaciones_A BEFORE INSERT ON validaciones
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(numero)+1 INTO :new.numero FROM validaciones;
    :new.estado := 'E';
    :new.fecha := SYSDATE;
END;
```

/

(2)

```
CREATE TABLE validaciones(
numero NUMBER(5) NOT NULL, 
fecha DATE NOT NULL,
justificacion VARCHAR(200) NULL,
estado CHAR(1) NOT NULL ,
correo_perfil VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
correo_profesional VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
codigo NUMBER(2) NOT NULL
);
```

Muchas gracias de antemano!!

@edit:
Todos los errores que me mandan son los siguientes:

```
Error starting at line : 438 in command -
    :new.estado := 'E'
Error report -
Unknown Command

SP2-0044: For a list of known commands enter HELP
and to leave enter EXIT.

Error starting at line : 439 in command -
    :new.fecha := SYSDATE
Error report -
Unknown Command


Error starting at line : 440 in command -
END
Error report -
Unknown Command
```

Comment: No sé donde estoy haciendo un update, se supone que la unica operación que estoy haciendo es un insert por eso en el trigger coloco BEFORE INSERT

Comment: Si perdon, lei mal. Va de vuelta, porque el error te lo tira en la linea 438 si tu trigger tiene 5 lineas???

Comment: Si, es que en total todo mi archivo SQL tiene como 443 lineas pero pues no coloco todo por lo que no creo que quieran ver el resto y puesto que el trigger esta afectando solo a la tabla validaciones no veo necesario colocar el resto

Comment: Y si incluis solo el trigger, y ejecutas solo su creacion, anda? entiendo lo de las lineas anteriores, pero no vaya a ser que el error venga de mas atras

Comment: En el archivo solo incluí el trigger y lo ejecuté y aun así me tira el mismo error

Comment: yo lo veo bien. salvo que nunca vi hacer el select directo a la variable, siempre vi un declare  y despues del select la asignacion. Sera eso? igual el error "que no describe nada" no ayuda...

Answer (score 0):

Prueba hacerlo así:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Ad_validaciones_A BEFORE INSERT ON validaciones
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(numero)+1, 'E', SYSDATE INTO :new.numero, :new.estado, :new.fecha FROM validaciones;
END;
```

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por contestar! ahora me tirá este error
Error starting at line : 438 in command -
END
Error report -
Unknown Command

Comment: Estás ejecutando todo tu archivo completo? O solo estás ejecutando el código del trigger? Si estás ejecutando todo tu archivo, es posible que tengas algún error de sintaxis en las líneas anteriores a la creación de tu trigger.